# IntersectionObserver is not defined

Tags: ts-mockito

I'm using ts-mockito with jsdom-global to add unit tests to a project which uses IntersectionObserver but unfortunately I'm stumbling on the following error:

```
     ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined
```

Does ts-mockito provide any way to mock or override IntersectionObserver?